# joint_state_publisher gui unresponsive

Tags: ros, joint-state-publisher, ros-kinetic, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this problem when I'm trying to move the sliders it is near impossible to move them anywhere, the gif below probably doesn't display so here's the imgur link to an example of a [non responsive joint_state_publisher gui](https://i.imgur.com/bofQRzp.gifv)
[image: non responsive joint_state_publisher gui]

This is on Kinetic, Xenial 16.04. Can anyone explain why and help me resolve this? I'm considering just creating a gui with rqt or just control it through a script if I can't resolve the above :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236231/joint_state_publisher-gui-unresponsive/) by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-06**:
If you can convert the `gifv` to a real `gif`, it should display fine.

**Comment by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) on 2016-06-07**:
Thank you will remember that for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't tell us, but you probably have another entity in your system publishing joint states. The `joint_state_publisher` will then set the sliders to those values. You can try and drag them, but the next incoming message will set them right back to where they where.

If you tell us a little more about the configuration of your node graph, we might be able to spot what is wrong.

Also: the `joint_state_publisher` UI is not meant for 'controlling a robot'. The only reason that UI exists is to provide you with an easy to change 'debug interface' to a joint states topic (ie: you use it when you have no real hardware which publishes real joint states). In a system with real hardware, the `joint_state_publisher` is used, but rarely with the `use_gui` parameter set to `true`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) on 2016-06-07**:
I know that the joint_state_publisher isn't meant for 'controlling a robot'. I'm writing a walkthrough for a friend of mine so we can build a robot together. The reason I asked was because I suspect that Kinetic distro might have something to do with it. [node graph](https://i.imgur.com/aTowLd1.png).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-07**:
Where is RViz in the graph you posted?

**Comment by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) on 2016-06-07**:
My bad, still learning to use rqt_graph :) [here it is](https://i.imgur.com/xde5jY4.png)